# Question on migration to Google Analytics for Firebase and BigQuery

Tags: firebase, google-bigquery, firebase-analytics

We currently have hundreds app on Google Analytics Mobile. We understand we need to migrate over to Google Analytics for Firebase. We have some questions which we need help to understand:

Current set up:

1. Currently we have multiple Google Cloud Platform accounts each with a number of API projects (one per app). Each API Project ID is used to created a Firebase Project for that Google Platform account.
2. In (old) Google Analytics Mobile we use the the REST API to get data for each app to be displayed in a custom dashboard:

   - sessions
   - unique users
   - demographics
   - geographic
   - affinity groups

Questions:

A) How do we replicate this in Google Analytics for Firebase? Is there a REST API for Google Analytics for Firebase to retrieve this information?

B) I understand an option is to migrate the Firebase analytics into BigQuery? Does BigQuery provide a REST API to extract the above data ? Is there a cost to using BigQuery.

C) Given we have multiple Google Cloud Platform accounts and each with multiple API Projects and linked to a Firebase project. Can all these Firebase projects be connected to the same BigQuery instance?

Many thanks

Comment: Google Analytics for Firebase has no REST API. It can only accumulate data from the integration with your app.

Comment: Hi Doug. Thanks for your reply. I was actually looking to understand if there is a REST API to get data out of Google Analytics for Firebase. We will feed data into it via our apps.